# How to fix GL_INVALID_ENUM error in function call?

Tags: opengl

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include "stdafx.h"

MainChar::MainChar(){ vboID = 0; vboIndexID = 0; glGetError(); }

MainChar::~MainChar(){}

void MainChar::MainChar_VBO_Func()
{
int error = glGetError();
if (error == GL_INVALID_ENUM){ std::cout << "Error before I even started!!! : " << error << "\n"; };

std::vector<GLdouble> mapVector{
-15.000000, -15.000000, 115.000000, -0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, -15.000000, -15.000000, -151.000000, -0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349,
15.000000, -15.000000, -115.000000, -0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349, 15.000000, -15.000000, 115.000000, -0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349,
-15.000000, 15.000000, 115.000000, 0.577349, 0.577349, -0.577349, -15.000000, 15.000000, -115.000000, 0.577349, -0.577349, -0.577349,
15.000000, 15.000000, -115.000000, 0.577349, 0.577349, 0.577349, 15.000000, 15.000000, 115.000000, 0.577349, -0.577349, 0.577349
                                };

//if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during mapVector decl: " << error << "\n"; }

// Setup Vertex Buffer Object
GLuint vboID = 0;
//if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during vboID decl: " << error << "\n"; }

glGenBuffers(1, &this->vboID);
//if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during GenBuffer call-VBO: " << error << "\n"; }

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vboID);
//if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during BindBuffer call-VBO: " << error << "\n"; }

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mapVector.size()*sizeof(GLdouble), &mapVector[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during BufferData call-VBO: " << error << "\n"; }
```

}

```
GLuint MainChar::MainChar_VBO_IndexBuffer_Func()
{

/* Index Buffer Initialization */

/* Index Buffer Data */

std::vector<GLuint> indexBuffer{
5, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 5, 3, 6, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8, 7, 4, 8, 3, 6,
8, 7, 5, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 6, 4, 8, 8, 7, 7, 5, 6, 2, 5, 1
};

// Set-up Index Buffer Object

    int error = glGetError();

glGenBuffers(1, &this->vboIndexID);
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during GenBuffer call-INDEX: " << error << "\n"; }

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vboIndexID);
if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during BindBuffer call-INDEX: " << error << "\n"; }

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer.size()*sizeof(GLuint), &indexBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during BufferData call-INDEX: " << error << "\n"; }

return indexBuffer.size();
```

The MainChar_VBO_Func() is called right after a check of glGetError to make sure no issues occur right beforehand, and the moment the func is called, the error is logged. I don't even pass an enum value when it log the error. Is it possibly not finding the gl context?
GLEW is def initiated, so I am unsure what the problem is.

The following is code which precedes and immediately follows the func call in question:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

//INIT SDL
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL, &displayWindow, &displayRenderer);
SDL_GetRendererInfo(displayRenderer, &displayRendererInfo);

/*TODO: Check that we have OpenGL */
if ((displayRendererInfo.flags & SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED) == 0 ||(displayRendererInfo.flags & SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE) == 0) {}

SDL_GL_CreateContext(displayWindow);
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

glewInit();
int error = glGetError();
if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during glewInit call: " << error << "\n"; };

Display_InitGL();
Display_SetViewport(800, 600);
if (error != GL_NO_ERROR){ std::cout << "Error during Display Set Viewport Issue: " << error << "\n"; };


// SET UP TEST OBJ
MainChar *player = new MainChar();
player->MainChar_VBO_Func();
unsigned int size = player->MainChar_VBO_IndexBuffer_Func();
float count = 0.0;
// END SET UP OF TEST OBJ


// Create VAO. Don't forget to enable all necessary states because the VAO starts with default state, cleaning all states prev called to do so.
GLuint VaoId;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
glBindVertexArray(VaoId);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
// End VAO init
```

Comment: For one thing, this is strange: `glEnableClientState (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);` and guaranteed to generate a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error on any implementation. The Element Array Buffer is used merely by having a non-zero one bound when you call `glDrawElements (...)` you do not have to enable a client state - there is no such client state to enable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Do `error = glGetError();` after each other call to the GL API for obvious reasons
- Note, that `glGetError()` may return multiple error enumerators, so you'd need to call this function in a loop until it returns `GL_NO_ERROR` or the errors will remain. Clearing errors this way before calling another GL function is possibly also necessary (one does usually not want to clear errors after every single GL call). However, I encountered sort of a bug lately, which caused an endless loop because `glGetError()` continuously returned the same error.
- Attach the [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/download.php), to avoid error check clutter
- If available (at runtime), use [ARB_debug_output](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) in a debug mode of your program, for the same reason.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `GL_ARB_debug_output` is often only listed in the extensions string if you create a special debug context. This sometimes leads people to believe that their implementation does not support the extension when it actually does. `GL_KHR_debug` is always reported though, even in a non-debug context. *Nevermind, I see that link is not to the `GL_ARB_debug_output` specficiation, but to a Wiki entry that already explains this (and is actually related to `GL_KHR_debug`).*

Comment: I did add more GetError calls last night. It did no good. I isolated the problem to this particular function. For whatever reason, this is failing to handle the context properly...

Comment: @user3204692: You need to include more context in your question, in particular show the sequence of events that leads up to calling `MainChar_VBO_Func (...)`. Because the way you make it sound here: *"Error before I even started!!! : "* it sounds like this is the first function your software calls immediately after context creation. In which case, I suspect GLEW is to blame.

Comment: "Before I even started" is meant to reference the function call itself, not the entire program as a whole.

Comment: Hmmm. Turns out I didn't pay proper attention to my use of glGetError. I added more "error = glGetError()" lines after each func so I wasn't just getting the error from 50 million lines before. :/ I found the problem but I still can't render from the vbo...any ideas with what I might be doing wrong on that front?